# correct way to perform an ajax synchronous POST and then submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got my ASP submit button

```
<asp:button runat="server" Text="Submit" id="btnSubmitOrder" OnClientClick="return SubmitOrder()" />
```

My Javascript function, SubmitOrder(), needs to perform a POST, and then based on the success of that POST, either allow the form submission (return true) or cancel it (return false)

```
function SubmitOrder() {

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: strURL,
        data: arrKeyVal,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.results.count > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

My concern is that since this is now deprecated, it may soon be obsolete.

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

So how should I handle this?  Knowing that I need to wait for a response before allowing the form submission to proceed.

Comment: Why do you need `async: false` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't believe I can cancel the form submission from an async callback function.

Comment: Didn't you consider `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: What do you think happens when your function is executed? And what do you think your return statements/values do? Where do they go? (It is far more important that you understand the *correct* answer to these questions than it is that you fix your form issue)

Comment: If the problem is that you need to perform the form submission in the success ajax function, just pass a callback as a function argument so that it will be called AFTER the post has been executed. Meanwhile, provide a sweet loading thing to keep the user entertained while his browser is not locked like it would be with a syncronous request. (or just submit the form if it is successful)

Comment: @briosheje Until Jacob's post below, I didn't think of just using Javascript to submit the form.  I think that is the simple answer to my simple problem :)

Comment: @adam : Yep but.. just don't use a syncronous request, that's the whole point to me :)

Comment: @briosheje Right, now that I realize I can submit the form in the async callback success method, won't be doing synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only cancel an event synchronously. One option is to not attach `SubmitOrder` to a form submit event, but rather just create a click handler, then actually submit the form in your ajax callback.

```
function SubmitOrder() {

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: strURL,
        data: arrKeyVal,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.results.count > 0) {
                $('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

...or you can do an Ajax submit of the form instead of a regular HTML form submit.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, will try it and report back.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function SubmitOrder() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: 'POST',
        url: strURL,
        data: arrKeyVal,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.results.count > 0) {
                $('form').submit();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: This function does not reference the form yet so you will need to select the form and then call submit.

Comment: Wouldn't `this.submit()` just call `SubmitOrder` all over again?

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `event`?